# Need Progress bar in red when the value is <0

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a progress bar to be inserted in html td.
the color of progress bar has to be green for the value >0 and
red for the value <0.
everything is working fine except when i enter value in less than 0, the bar
is not changing itself to red.
pls help.`

```js
$('.my-progress').each(function(index) {
  var progress = $(this).find('.my-progress-value').html();
  $(this).css("width", progress);
  if (parseInt(progress) == 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
  } else if (parseInt(progress) < 10) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  } else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  }
});
```

```css
.my-progress-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.my-progress {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 8px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="my-progress-container">
        <div class="my-progress">
          <span class="my-progress-value">9%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have removed the [tag:java] tag from your question -- I really don't see how this question relates to Java programming. Please indicate if I did this in error.

Comment: Color of progress bar has been defined through javascript / jquery indeed.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with Java programming? You do know that they are completely different programming languages, right?

Comment: Not really , I am not a hard core programmer.

Comment: Then this is a good time to learn this. By mistagging your question, you risk annoying Java experts who come to the question expecting it to have Java relevance. Question titles and tags are the most important part of your question since these are what bring the correct experts to your question. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some changes to the original code, percentage graphic is where the graphic is drawn.

Check the snippet.

```js
$( function() {
      let sal = $(".pl");
      
      let progressbarSize = 100; //100%
      
      $(".progressbar").css("width", progressbarSize + "px");
      
      $(".negative, .positive").css({width : (progressbarSize / 2) + "px", height : "20px", display : "inline"});
      
      $(".negative").css("backgroundColor", "red")
      .css("float", "left");
      
      $(".positive").css("backgroundColor", "green")
      .css("float", "right");
      
      $(sal).each(function(index, element){
        let currentValue = parseInt($(element).text());
        
        //console.log(currentValue);
        
        if (currentValue >= 0 && currentValue <= progressbarSize){

          //console.log(currentValue);
          $(element).next().children().children(".negative").css("backgroundColor", "");
          $(element).next().children().children(".positive")
          .css("width", (currentValue / 2) + "px")
          .css("margin-right", (progressbarSize / 2) - (currentValue / 2)  +"px");

        }else if(currentValue >= (progressbarSize * -1) && currentValue < 0){
          
          //console.log(currentValue);
          currentValue *= -1;
          $(element).next().children().children(".positive").css("backgroundColor", "");
          $(element).next().children().children(".negative")
          .css("width", (currentValue / 2) + "px")
          .css("margin-left", (progressbarSize / 2) - (currentValue / 2)  +"px");
        }else{
          
          $(element).next().children().children().hide(); //Hide the both, possitive and negative.
          
        }
        
      });
      
      
      
      
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
       
    
    td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    }
    </style>
    
    
    <body>
    <table>     
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Percentage number</th>
                <th>% Graphic</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="nm">Nitin</td>
                <td class="pl">-1000</td>
                <td class="pct"> <div class="progressbar"><div class="negative"></div><div class="positive"></div></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="nm">Suman</td>
                <td class="pl">-5</td>
                <td class="pct"><div class="progressbar"><div class="negative"></div><div class="positive"></div></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="nm">Nitin</td>
                <td class="pl">-100</td>
                <td class="pct"> <div class="progressbar"><div class="negative"></div><div class="positive"></div></div></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="nm">Nitin</td>
                <td class="pl">50</td>
                <td class="pct"> <div class="progressbar"><div class="negative"></div><div class="positive"></div></div></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="nm">Nitin</td>
                <td class="pl">55</td>
                <td class="pct"> <div class="progressbar"><div class="negative"></div><div class="positive"></div></div></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td class="nm">Nitin</td>
                <td class="pl">100</td>
                <td class="pct"> <div class="progressbar"><div class="negative"></div><div class="positive"></div></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
       
      
     </body>
```

Comment: I know i am missing something.

Comment: can that be done through applying two different css class 
.green class for positive and .red class for negative?

Comment: If you mean put negative value to the width, that means, the element with negative width don't will be visible, no matters if it a class with css properties or style property because is the same and don't will be visible.

Comment: ok, then can it be done choosing a mid point of div
towards left in red for negative value and towards right in green for positive??

Comment: Yes! with 2 td that can be possible. Try do that and i will help you if you have some issues with that.

Comment: can anyone help to fetch values of progress bar automatically from td class ".pl" on urgent basis

Comment: I make some changes, i don't know if its this what you want, check the snippet!

Comment: Amazingly working, I am not a programmer so didn't think that it could work like that successfully. And I took 2 classes unnecessarily ".pct" and ".pl".
whereas I wanted to have only 1 class with bar and value both in that.

Is it possible to remove class ".pl" and use".pct" only with values and bar in same td ??
Also i have same in excel which looks annoying when text comes over the bars, So if possibly shift the values either on right side or in center of td between progress bars without having reflection of bar colors on background of value??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233849/discussion-between-avi-and-alumno-cabreado).

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code appears to be the problem.

```
if (parseInt(progress) == 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
    $(this).css("background-color", "lightgrey");
} else if (parseInt(progress) < 10) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
} else {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
}
```

If `parseInt(progress)` is lower than 0, it is also lower than 10. Therefore, the second if-statement will be called, instead of the last one.

Comment: I tried 0 instead 10 as well,
not working